# Best way to refactor if statement method

Tags: c#, dictionary, refactoring

I currently have  a method that I'm hard coding the value that needs to be validate in the if statement and then I'm   running  the method that match the name I'm hardcoding.
Here is my code

```
  public Class Name 
   public static Dictionary<string, ValueMap> Name1= new Dictionary<string, ValueMap>
     public static Dictionary<string, ValueMap> Name2= new Dictionary<string, ValueMap>

  public Class compare
 public string Test (string sample, string Name)
            {

                if (sample == "Name1")
                {

                    var results = MethodName (sample, Name.Name1);//call method name Name1

                    return "";
                }
                if (sample == "Name2")
                {
                    var results = MethodName (sample, Name.Name2);  //call method name Name2  

                    return "";
                }
               if (sample == "Name3")
                {
                    var results = MethodName (sample, Name.Name3);    //call method name Name3

                    return "";
                }

                else
                {
                    return ""; ;
                }

            }
```

I don't want to add an if statement every time I need to add a different method inside my MethodName or hardcode the values inside my if statement so I was wondering if there is a way I  can just look for the method inside the compare class that match the string sample and pass this  method to my var results = MethodName (sample, Name.Name3);

Example something like this

```
 public Class Name 
   public static Dictionary<string, ValueMap> Name1= new Dictionary<string, ValueMap>
     public static Dictionary<string, ValueMap> Name2= new Dictionary<string, ValueMap>

     public Class Test
  string sample = Name1
         public string Test (string sample, string Name, Name name)
                    {

                            var results = MethodName (sample, Name1 -pass the method inside the compare class  that match the name inside the sample string );

                            return "";
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            return sample name was not found ; ;
                        }
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Sure, you could have a `Dictionary<string, Action<string>>` and store actions that call the methods for every string.

Comment: Could you please provide real C# sample code, which ideally makes sense? For example, you always return an empty `string` from your `Test` method, regardless of the `sample` value. It seems `results` is never used. As @gunr2171 already noted, particularly look at the [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) section. If you use three backticks in the first and last lines, you can simply copy-paste your C# code from your IDE. If you want to share an indented code snippet, outdent it, copy it, re-indent it, and paste in stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score -2):

One answer is using switch case.
And the second one is use Change of Responsibility pattern.
Chain of responsibility replaces if clauses.

Comment: Do you mean _Chain_ of Responsibility? _Change_ of Responsibility doesn't exist.